# Performance Problem with Clojure Array

Tags: performance, arrays, clojure

This piece of code is **very** slow.  Execution from the slime-repl on my netbook takes a couple minutes.

```
(def test-array (make-array Integer/TYPE 400 400 3))

(doseq [x (range 400), y (range 400), z (range 3)]
   (aset test-array x y z 0))
```

Conversely, this code runs really fast:

```
(def max-one (apply max (map (fn [w] (apply max (map #(first %) w))) test-array)))
(def max-two (apply max (map (fn [w] (apply max (map #(second %) w))) test-array)))
(def max-three (apply max (map (fn [w] (apply max (map #(last %) w))) test-array)))
```

Does this have something to do with chunked sequences?  Is my first example just written wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're hitting Java reflection. This blog post has a workaround:

http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/10/15/multidim-arrays/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I thought it might be reflection, but I am not getting any reflection warnings?  Any idea why not?

Comment: Apparently `*warn-on-reflection*` doesn't always tell the whole story... See also http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/08/06/what-warn-on-reflection-doesnt-tell-you-about-arrays/

Comment: With Clojure 1.2 you should get more reflection warnings on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You might get better performance from one of the four Clojure matrix implementations available via a single interface core.matrix: [at clojars](https://clojars.org/net.mikera/core.matrix), [at github](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix).